# unexpected t_if error in value

Tags: php

I looked around a bit, but I have not found anything.

I have this code, I tried to make some changes, but I always get the same error T_IF in the value part.

How should I modify it to not have errors?

```
else {
    echo "<form action='create-channel.php' method='POST'>
        <input class='form-control' name='n_channel' type='text' id='n_channel' placeholder='Name Channel' value=" if(isset($error)){echo "$_POST['n_channel']"; } "></p>
        <input class='form-control' name='p_channel' type='text' placeholder='Password'></p>
        <input class='btn btn-primary xst-margin' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /> 
    </form>";
}
```

Comment: Where is you `IF` condition?

Comment: You can't an if statement in the middle if a string

Comment: value=" if(isset($error)){echo "$_POST['n_channel']"; }

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an `if` statement right while you are `echo`'ing.

You have to echo the first part. Do your `if` check. Then re-echo the last part :

```
else {
  echo 'first part';
  if(isset($error)) {
    echo "$_POST['n_channel']"; 
  }
  echo 'last part';
}
```

Comment: Can't get an answer edgeways today.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `echo` or have an `if` inside an echo for a start.  Try something like this :

```
else {
    $channel = isset($error) ? $_POST['n_channel'] : '';
    echo "<form action='create-channel.php' method='POST'>";
    echo "<input class='form-control' name='n_channel' type='text' id='n_channel' placeholder='Name Channel' value=" . $channel . "></p>";
    echo "<input class='form-control' name='p_channel' type='text' placeholder='Password'></p>";
    echo "<input class='btn btn-primary xst-margin' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Basically if the `$error` is set then `$channel` = `$_POST['n_channel']` otherwise it equals nothing.  Then concatenate it in the main string.

Comment: You can have short if statement in middle of string `"a".($c ? true : false)."b"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$error = 111;
if( 1 == 2 )
        echo 1;
else { echo "<form action='create-channel.php' method='POST'>
    <input class='form-control' name='n_channel' type='text' id='n_channel' placeholder='Name Channel' value=";
    if(isset($error)){echo $_POST['n_channel'];}
    echo "></p>
    <input class='form-control' name='p_channel' type='text' placeholder='Password'></p>
    <input class='btn btn-primary xst-margin' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /> 
                                </form>";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong string concatenation. Instead of

```
placeholder='Name Channel' value=" if(isset($error)){echo "$_POST['n_channel']"; } "></p>
```

use

```
placeholder='Name Channel' value='".(isset($error) ? $_POST['n_channel'] : '')."'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `if` keyword in the middle of a string:

```
echo "...." if(isset($error)){echo "...."
```

You need to conclude the first `echo` statement, *then* proceed to the next statement:

```
echo "....";
if(isset($error)){
    echo "....";
}
```

You also then immediately follow that with an unexpected string:

```
echo "....";
if(isset($error)){
    echo "....";
}
"...."
```

Since you're on a new statement, you need to supply a command of some kind.  A string by itself isn't a statement to be executed.  I'm guessing you want to `echo` that string:

```
echo "....";
if(isset($error)){
    echo "....";
}
echo "....";
```

PHP code is a series of discrete imperative statements to be executed.  You can't mix different statements like this and expect the interpreter to know what you mean, it just confuses the interpreter.  Each statement needs to be syntactically correct and needs to be concluded with a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do it this way:

```
else {
  echo 'first part of your string';
  if(isset($error)) {
    echo $_POST['n_channel']; 
  }
  echo 'last part of your string';
}
```

or

```
else {
    echo 'first part of your string' . 
    (isset($error) ? $_POST['n_channel'] : '')
    . 'last part of your string';
}
```

using ternary operator

In your case below 2 codes will work:

```
else {
    echo '<form action='create - channel . php' method='POST'>
        <input class='form
    - control' name='n_channel' type='text' id='n_channel' placeholder='Name Channel' value="';
    if (isset($error)) {
        echo $_POST['n_channel'];
    }
    echo '"></p>
        <input class='form - control' name='p_channel' type='text' placeholder='Password'></p>
        <input class='btn btn - primary xst - margin' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
                                                            </form>';
}
```

or

```
else {
    echo '<form action='create - channel . php' method='POST'>
        <input class='form
    - control' name='n_channel' type='text' id='n_channel' placeholder='Name Channel' value="'.
    ((isset($error)) ? $_POST['n_channel'] : '' )
    . '"></p>
        <input class='form - control' name='p_channel' type='text' placeholder='Password'></p>
        <input class='btn btn - primary xst - margin' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
                                                            </form>';
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. it is working for me:

```
echo "<form action='create-channel.php' method='POST'>
        <input class='form-control' name='n_channel' type='text' id='n_channel' placeholder='Name Channel' value=".isset($_POST['n_channel'])." ></p>
        <input class='form-control' name='p_channel' type='text' placeholder='Password'>
        <input class='btn btn-primary xst-margin' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /> 
                                                            </form>";
```